# The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json ver 9 and 10

Tags: c#, json.net

I am constantly plagues by issues where Newtonsoft.Json seems to be available in multiple versions within my project.  The problem is that it is not.  I have 10 installed in the project, and that's the only DLL that's in place.  The GAG does not have the dll, and the web.config seems correct.

```
The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

Has anyone else seen this?  Is there a way to specify the version to use at code level, or within the web.config?

Answer (score 24):

This seems to be due to multiple invisible references to the Newtonsoft.Json DLL

1. Right click on your project and select Unload Project.
2. Now right click again and select Edit MyProject.csproj (or whatever your project is called)
3. Search for Newtonsoft.Json within this file.
4. If you find multiple Reference elements with different versions, delete all but the newest version
5. Save the file
6. Right click on your project again and select Reload Project

The errors should be gone.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only answer that actually made sense. Also note for other people with the same issue, there may be a reference without a specific version number, I deleted that one and it seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

try install previous version of newtonsoft.json

in my circumstance, I updated newtonsoft to 11.0.2 from 6.
Compiling gave this error message that include ver 6 and 11.
I tried uninstall, but i did not,  cause of dependencies.
but I used this command and I succeded to downgrade.
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.1

and this error gone.

Comment: I confirm that downgrading from 11.0.2 to 11.0.1 solved the problem. Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.1

unbelievable :)

Comment: Also had this same issue today. Downgrading to 11.0.1 resolved the issue. I used the Nuget Package Manager to do it, rather than the command.

Answer (score 2):

You should force to load only one assembly, I suggest to load the latest one. You can check if all referenced assemblies use that version. If not, you have to add this to your `web.config` file:

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This will force to use version 10 of `Newtonsoft.Json`. Make sure to remove version 9 from the `bin` folder.

Comment: Yeah, that's in place.  I have the following:

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Did you remove the reference to version 9 as suggested?

Comment: No reference to version 9 anywhere in the web.config.   Is there any place else I should look?  Machine.config, maybe?

Comment: In your project references.

Comment: Which file is that?  I've looked for the public key token across all files in the project, and the only reference is in the web.config, which is pointing to version 10.

Comment: Your csproj file. Also that of other projects you reference.

Comment: No, none of that worked.  There are no references to Newtonsoft.Json v9 anywhere in the solution.

Comment: I have since tried:

- Dropped packages folder, and removed the Nuget Cache, then reloaded everything.  That didn't resolve the issue.

- There are two projects that use the DLL.  I removed it, and re-added it to both.

What did eventually work, but is not a good solution, is that I took the entire solution over to the production server, and compiled it there.  That worked, but locally, I can't  seem to get passed this v9 vs v10 error.

Comment: That is strange. If there are no references and no assemblies there, where does it come from then?

Comment: That is the question.  Its definitely related to my PC, since I was able to compile on a different machine without issues.  I was able to get around the issue on my local PC by including the assembly in the project.  Once included, it looks to that first, then elsewhere.  The question, of course, is where that elsewhere is, so I can update it or make sure it is excluded somehow.

Comment: +1 for the tip of removing any older assemply. this produced constantly an error... even with assemblybinding